# Difference between new-template.cabal and stack.yaml

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

I want to use [`reactive-banana`](https://github.com/HeinrichApfelmus/reactive-banana/) in my new Haskell project. I never used [cabal-install](https://wiki.haskell.org/Cabal-Install) or [`stack`](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack) before. I created a directory and initialized project files in it using `stack new`. I see now 2 files in the directory: `new-template.cabal` and `stack.yaml`.

How do I set dependencies and make sure they are downloaded and compiled?

At first I tried to add `- reactive-banana-0.8.0.2` in `stack.yaml` under `extra-deps:`,  but both `stack build` and `stack solver` didn't download it. Then I augmented a part called `library` in `new-template.cabal` to this:

```
library
  hs-source-dirs:      src
  exposed-modules:     Lib
  build-depends:       base >= 4.7 && < 5
                     , reactive-banana >= 0.8
  default-language:    Haskell2010
```

Every time I tried to run `stack build`, it crashed with an error and suggestion to add some package to `stack.yaml` under `extra-deps:`, and this happened three times until finally all packages installed, and I could import them in `stack ghci` REPL.

So my question is, what is the idiomatic way to use `stack`? Which of these 2 files should I use to specify dependencies and other project metadata? What is the sample workflow of an average Haskell developer with `stack`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using `stack` I generally don't put any versions bounds in my `.cabal` file. I let the `resolver` and `extra-deps` setting in the `stack.yaml` file determine which versions of packages to select.

Here is a `stack.yaml` file which brings in reactive-banana-0.8.1.2:

```
flags: {}
packages:
- '.'
extra-deps:
- reactive-banana-0.8.1.2
- psqueues-0.2.0.2
resolver: lts-2.17
```

In my `.cabal` file I just have:

```
  build-depends:       base >= 4.7 && < 5, reactive-banana
```

The reactive-banana version is pinned by the stack.yaml file.

If you want to use GHC 7.10 change the resolver to something like `nightly-2015-06-17`.

I determine the `extra-deps` iteratively, by just running `stack build` and adding whatever dependencies are missing to the `stack.yaml` file until all dependencies are satisfied.

You will only need to do this with packages which are not in [Stackage](http://www.stackage.org/) - like reactive-banana. A great many of commonly used packages are in Stackage and their versions will be determined by the `resolver` setting.

Comment: I wouldn't specify the version to the bugfix release if it isn't needed. Probably something like `reactive-banana >= 0.8` is more than enough most of the time.

Comment: You can, but the version selected will be determined by the `stack.yaml` file where you have to give a specific version.

Comment: This actually works very neatly - `stack.yaml` freezes the version to ensure a reproducible build, while the cabal file can be used to inform users how far they can deviate from the fixed versions (I only noticed this after reading your comments).

Answer (score 2):

In the default configuration, stack works with two package databases: a centralised per-user one and a project-specific one. The centralised database only pulls packages from [Stackage](http://www.stackage.org/), a subset of Hackage with known-to-be-compatible packages, while you can put whatever you want on the project-specific database. All packages you use must be in the cabal file, but those not on Stackage (that is, the ones that will go to the project-specific database) must also be listed in the extra-deps section of `stack.yaml`. `reactive-banana` is not on Stackage, so you need to add it to `stack.yaml`, like this:

```
# etc.
extra-deps:
- reactive-banana-0.8.1.2
# etc.
```

`stack solver` can fill in the extra dependencies in `stack.yaml` for you.